# Duplicate closing window, scrolling when previewing other question is not resetted

Tags: bug, design, vote-to-close, user-experience

When closing a question as a duplicate, one doesn't always find the perfect duplicate on the first page.

When searching to close a question today, I noticed that previewing the question didn't reset the scrolltop to the top of the page.

Personally, that's a bit annoying, cause if I find a very similar title, I am thinking that it will probably have been closed as well by a topic I had in mind originally but didn't found through my query.

Since the duplicate is at the top of the preview, I have to scroll to the top, which can be annoying when not finding a duplicate and having to return to the search page